# Multiple Class Dependencies

Tags: c++, oop, class-design

I am trying to make a class that contains two other objects, and those object should maintain a pointer to the class they are contained in. For

For example... (I am only using on object instance variable, in the final imagine there is a class very similar to ClassB)

This is just my main.cpp, figured I would include it to be thorough...

```
//Filename: main.cpp
#include "ClassA.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    ClassA *a = new ClassA();
    // There would be some more here in the real code
    return 0;
}
```

Now for the classes in questions....

```
//Filename: classA.hpp
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include "ClassB.hpp"

class ClassA {
public:
    ClassA() {
        b = new B(this);
    };
    virtual ~ClassA();

private:
    ClassB *b;
};

#endif //CLASSA_H
```

Now here is the other file...

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

#include "ClassB.hpp"

//Filename: classB.hpp
class ClassB {
public:
    ClassB(ClassA *parent) {
        this->parent = parent;
    };
    virtual ~ClassB();
private:
    A *parent;
};

#endif //CLASSB_H
```

When I try to compile this, I am getting the error "error: ClassA does not name a type" and then of course "error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token"
My guess is this has something to with them including one another?

(Not sure if it matters, but in the actual code, the function implementations are in a .cpp file that includes the header. Would that do it?)

Comment: Now that it is solved... I partially miss Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
class ClassA;
```

before ClassB definition;
Simple example:

```
class B;

class A {
        B * b;
};

class B {
        A * a;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was it. Thank you.
I programmed C++ a while back, switched to Java, and just recently came back to C++. Makes me realize how nice Java is for some of this stuff with classes.

Comment: The class declaration/definition syntax in C++ is insane.  Well, most of C++ is insane in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming these are typos but I may be mistaken  `classA` while you have `A *`.

What you need to do is forward declare the classes ie.

```
class ClassA;
class ClassB{
    ...
};
```

and the same for `ClassA`

```
class ClassB;
class ClassA{
      ....
};
```

Comment: Ah yes, good catch. Just typed this up real quick as an example.

Comment: Why forward declare both of the classes, not one? Just formard declare classB, and include the header of classA in classB header.

In either way, when you implement the class methods inline, compiler would't agree unless it finds complete definition of other class, if method/member of other class is being access. Better to implement in implementation (CPP) file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one of two ways; either you can make ClassA and ClassB implement an interface (or superclass since you're in C++) and then have each class have a pointer defined as the interface.  The second way you could do this is to use a forward declaration before each class (i.e. ClassA forward declaration before defining ClassB and ClassB forward declaration before defining ClassA).

Comment: I don't think we know enough to suggest using inheritance here.

Comment: I would agree that it may not be the perfect solution in some cases; However, it was not the only option in my solution.  My other solution was the same as yours utilizing a forward declaration.